# How to condense academic CV in one slide

Tags: career-path, postdocs, interview

I am giving in the next days a presentation to a UK university, as a part of an interview for a post-doc position.

The PI of the lab asked me to put one slide at the beginning with my academic CV.

However, academic CV is in general long and I have no clue on what I should put in this slide and what not, beside the obvious things.

What should this slide contain?
Which is the common practice for this?

I am sure I will need to add:

- Previous degrees (Bsc, Msc).
- Phd

What I do not know:

- Professional experiences?
- Teaching experiences?
- List of papers?
- List of conferences?
- List of journals for which I served as a reviewer?

Comment: Make it readable. Make it "interesting". Make the last bullet "Many more things, too numerous to mention"

Answer (score 2):

I would treat it as a bullet point summary of your accomplishments:

- PhD/dissertation
- Notable experiences (e.g., teaching, internships, and professional positions, but not the typical TA/RA positions)
- Awards
- Summary of publications (e.g., "8 publications in venues such as A and B")

There are no standard rules for this. The goal is to convince them you are worthy of a job, so eliminate any noise and only provide the highlights. They can refer to your actual CV if they want more details.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the EMPTY slide as a TWO-Column page as shown in the picture below.

The following picture is just the DUMBEST work I have ever done, but in short time, I could manage only this much to give my answer. You need to add color and flair to it

Good luck !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I typically do two slides for short self-presentation, but the first one is relevant for you.

## First slide

- *19xx
- BSc 20xx, MSc 20yy
- PhD 20aa from Burkington
- Venia legendi 20zz from ZU Zaplin
- Tenured at Marward at 20mm

## Second slide

- Current research focus
- Further research interests
- A fancy research video

Comment: Why would you put your birth year on there (I presume that's what *19xx refers to)?

Comment: Because getting a PhD while being young enough is an achievement?

Comment: Young enough for what? many countries have anti age discrimination laws, so it would not be an advantage.

Comment: You'd want to convey the dynamics of your career, won't you?

Comment: @OlegLobachev I would say that the difference between your BSc, MSc and PhD graduation years is enough to show that you have obtained your degrees in a short time, which I understand it is the idea you actually want to convey. Unless you started your college studies before standard age and want to display that.

Comment: Now old German specifica comes in, earlier they had no BSc, only MSc-analogon.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a "multiple timelines" slide.

You could make a slide showing multiple arrows representing time, each one depicting one dimension of your scientific experience. Here are the dimensions I recently presented using this slide format :
1. Academic affiliations, classes I was in charge of
2. Lab affiliations
3. The research projects I participated in
4. Papers and conferences (represented as dashes of different colors with a highlight on written publications)

This list of ideas needs to be adapted to your own experience. I think that the main objective would be to make it as simple as possible and to refine your different points in your speech.

Generally speaking, I think that this kind of visual can help your audience to grasp your whole experience in a few minutes and more importantly, to grasp it's consistency.